# Invariant Violation in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use ListView on my js page and I am getting no data on my screen. The screen is totally blank. Below is the image of the empty screen. I am getting a warning.

[image]

Below is my code where I am calling the ListView:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ListView } from 'react-native';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from '../reducers/ServiceReducer';
import ServiceItem from './ServiceItem';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 353,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingLeft: 20,
  },
});


const store = createStore(reducers);

class AutoCompActivity extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    });
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.services);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ListView 
          enableEmptySections={true}
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => 
            <ServiceItem services={rowData} />
          }
        />
      </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { services: state.services };
};
const ConnectedAutoCompActivity = connect(mapStateToProps)(AutoCompActivity);


const app1 = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedAutoCompActivity />
  </Provider>
)

export default app1;
```

My ServiceItem.js file is below:

```
 import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, ImagePropertiesAndroid } from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { getTheme } from 'react-native-material-kit';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import * as actions from '../actions';


const theme = getTheme();
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
      marginTop: 20,
    },
    title: {
        top: 20,
        left: 80,
        fontSize: 24,
    },
    image: {
        height: 100,
    },
    action: {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        color: 'white',
    },
    icon: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 15,
        left: 0,
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    },
  });


   const ServiceItem=(props)=>{
   return(
        <View>
                 <Text style={[theme.cardTitleStyle, styles.title]}>{props.services.services}</Text>


        </View>


     )

   }

   export default connect(null, actions)(ServiceItem);
```

My Json file is very simple:

```
    [
  {
    "services": "Test1"
  },

  {
    "services": "Test2"
  },
  {
    "services": "Test3"
  },
    {
    "services": "Test4"
  },
    {
    "services": "Test4"
  }

  ]
```

My service.Reducer has the following code:

```
    import services from './services.json';

const initialState = {
    services
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I checked my code several times and could not find any issue. I also installed react redux. Store is defined as const in my code. I am just trying to show each service as 
test1, 
test2 on my phone

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to wrap your Main file with the provider, then only the child components be connected to the store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `Provider` **inside** connected component.

The connected component should be wrapped inside `<Provider>`. Replace your code with the following and it will work as expected.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ListView } from 'react-native';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from '../reducers/ServiceReducer';
import ServiceItem from './ServiceItem';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 353,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingLeft: 20,
  },
});


const store = createStore(reducers);

class AutoCompActivity extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    });
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.services);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ListView 
          enableEmptySections={true}
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => 
            <ServiceItem services={rowData} />
          }
        />
      </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { services: state.services };
};

const ConnectedAutoCompActivity = connect(mapStateToProps)(AutoCompActivity);


const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedAutoCompActivity />
  </Provider>
)


export default App;
```

Comment: I am not seeing anything on my screen now. It is totally blank.

Comment: Hi Rahul , Thank you. There was a small issue in my jspn file. Once I fixed it, the code started working.